# Classifying the ethical characteristics of entities by cognitive properties, non-human-specific

Tags: ethics, metaethics, being, cognition, post-humanism

I am wondering if any theorists have developed a way of classifying entities by their cognitive properties in order to build general theories such as ethics, based on such properties. It should classify, group, and distinguish entities by their cognitive characteristics rather than something like biological species. Therefore hypothetically, a very smart dog and very stupid human might be grouped more similarly, at least in certain regards, than two humans. There may be different subgroups of humans. It would also extend to hypothetical entities such as alien minds or digital ones.

The classification would take into account all aspects of cognition and consciousness. For example, to what extent can the entity feel aversive or afflictive sensations like pain. To what extent does the entity have a concept of self-awareness. To what extent is the entity capable of free thought and self-modification of beliefs. And many, many more highly specific aspects.

If this does not exist, then suggest a framework for doing so.

(To give an inkling at what I mean by “many more aspects”, I think I am a little influenced by Heidegger’s analysis of what it even means to be a “being”, how there may be different “levels” or aspects of “being” something. Thus, it opens the question of to what extent different humans actually have different ways of “being”, and from a cognitive perspective, are technically different classes of “beings” altogether. The purpose would have nothing to do with some sort of social Darwinist program, but rather to see the world more precisely and cast off dogmas, and therefore build a better ethical theory which is more precise and encompasses more than just humans, animals for example.)

Comment: To my surprise, this was the first use of the tag [`post-humanism`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posthumanism) on Philosophy Stack Exchange.

Comment: If you're looking to get an order such as rock < virus < bacteria < mushroom < tree < oyster < fish, that's one thing, but if you're looking to get an order such as my_least_favourite_humans < dogs < average_humans < my_favourite_humans, then that doesn't sound like "building a theory of ethics" so much as it sounds like "writing an apology of nazism".

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is: To base an ethical system on the cognitive capabilities of the beings involved.

Just to imagine what this means:

- Intelligence tests from psychology classify human beings
  according to a broad spectrum of cognitive capabilities.
- It is a basic principle of most ethics that moral
  rights do not depend on cognitive capabilites. Instead,
  the ability to feel pain is considered an essential and relevant
  criterion how to behave with such beings.

Hence the idea, to link *moral* to *intelligence*, is a severe violation of a basic ethical principle. To expand this link to all smart systems seems to me material for a horror story.

Comment: Well, they did say they were influenced by Heidegger.

Comment: Point two is very contentious (how exactly do you quantify that?), it can hardly be used to argue that a "basic" ethical principle is being violated by his presupposition. It can even be easily contested that _duties_ at least do require intelligence because, sure, dogs, chimps and babies may feel pain, but they can't effectively be held responsible for anything they do. Better just say that it would be a violation in ethical systems where minimizing pain is a basic principle.

Comment: @Mutoh I made a change in point two, skipping the duties; thanks.

Comment: If you base moral value only on the ability to feel pain, then you have to grant many animals the same moral value as humans. Even a committed vegan doesn't value a rabbit's life the same as a human's. If you wish to justify a moral system that values a single human life above a single animal's life, you have to pick a relevant characteristic of humans that animals lack. What morally relevant characteristics are available, save intelligence?

Comment: @causative Our species-centered ethics for humans bases moral rights not on intelligence. The degree of intelligence distinguishes humans from other animals. But just as it is no criterion for moral rights for humans, I do not see a reason, why it should be a criterion for animals in general or for smart systems. While the ability to feel pain generalizes to all animals, and probably also to future smart systems. – Nevertheless, the task is immense to design an ethics which includes all smart systems and all living systems. As far as I know, nobody has yet presented a consistent proposal.

Comment: A tetraplegic person may not be able to feel pain in most of their body; does that make them less important in the eye of the "essential and relevant criterion" that is the ability to feel pain? How about a person undergoing depression, whose psychological state makes their ability to feel emotions and pain much duller than when they were not depressed?

Comment: @JoWehler How can you justify having "species-centered ethics for humans" - why should a being's species have any impact on their moral value beyond their own characteristics as an individual? Imagine you met an intelligent space alien. You can't use the alien's species to decide its moral value, and so you would use the fact of its intelligence.

Comment: @causative Of course I cannot and I did not justify species-centered ethics. But that's the baseline and provides a realistic point of departure. In particular it shows what species-centeredness means.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations on being the first to use the post-humanism tag! I suspect there are two inter-related and fundamental difficulties facing your intriguing suggestion. The lesser of the two is the need to identify a schema for taking into account 'all aspects of cognition and consciousness'. I have no idea how you might go about that successfully without risk of anthropomorphism, since you would necessarily be making assumptions about what it means to be like a dog, say, based on your own experience of human cognition and awareness. The second, is that you could only infer what cognitive properties non-human entities possess- you have no way of asking them. I see little chance of determining in a meaningful way whether a cow, say, is capable of self-modification of beliefs (notwithstanding their tendency to ruminate), let alone the 'many, many more highly specific aspects' of bovine intellectual life you expect to probe.

Even if you could overcome those difficulties, your assumption that the outcome would provide a foundation for better ethical theories is one that might need some justification, particularly if you were relying on it to provide the motivation for all of the work involved.

Answer (score 2):

**Insults according to notions of intelligence: Perspectives from education and newsmedia**

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/bld.12470

> Background
> The terms idiot, imbecile, and moron are generally associated with notions of intelligence, having served both scientific and mundane roles across cultural-historical contexts and in many different countries. This study seeks to explore the degree to which the use of these terms is an everyday part of our lives and to map out the meanings being attached to them.

> Conclusion
> This study shows how widely these words are used across social contexts, and suggests that as with other historical terms for marginalized populations we need to regard them as slurs and treat them as taboo.

The effort to classify cognitive-emotive capabilities is likely to continue with human-human, human-animal, and human-AI interactions, but don't bet the farm on the emergence of any universally accepted model for cognitive-emotional intelligence. This is because the human community itself is a network of agents with Distributed Intelligence (DI) in which each person is a node in the network, the nodes of implicit intelligence, and there is the capacity for self-other communication impacting the implicit intelligence with explicit language. Good luck with that project!

You have already mentioned the danger of Social Darwinism, beyond that there is biological racism and other historical examples of unethical application of distributed human intelligence. Blowing hydrocarbons into the atmosphere at the fossil-fuel burn-rate of modern economics, creating money from thin-air via banks and governments, and destroying biodiversity at the interest rate to accumulate financial claims, is likely to be recognized by future ethical philosophers as an unethical experiment conducted by the present generation at the potential cost of enjoying similar prosperity by future generations. But I hope I am wrong about that outcome! Bad ideas cause bad outcomes - this is the essence of the message of the Hebrew prophets - but they go too far in blaming the people for collective ignorance whereas God and/or Nature give us cognitive limits!

**EDIT - The Major Concerns Regarding the DSM as a Diagnostic System**

https://drzur.com/dsm-critique/#major

> The concern with the DSM did not start with the DSM-5. It has been voiced for many decades prior to the May/2013 publication of the DSM-5. Diagnosis of “mental illness” has always been more an art than a science. DSM-based research has repeatedly shown very poor reliability and, therefore, questionable validity.

The social project of psychoanalysis and/or psychotherapy is the clinical diagnosis and treatment of mental (cognitive-emotional) disorders. This project is a failure on so many levels despite the best efforts of the so-called mental health professionals. But such failure is not at all surprising given the nature of humans as political animals seeking social status and economic gain in their role(s) as experts or professionals.

Sigmund Freud maps the ego to the child in early life, and he maps the paternalistic mother and father (whose actions are supposed to be for the good of the child but are not always good for the child) to the superego domain of the ego - to the memories of the paternalistic parents. We see that paternalism recapitulates itself in the parent-child and healer-patient relationships and for the most part remains unconscious so the experts can gain status and money by helping those with cognitive-emotional disabilities. The experts take up the role of the paternalistic parents independent of whether they are competent or incompetent in those roles so the only distinction is what constitutes competency in the expert roles?

**APA Ethical Principals of Psychologists and Code of Conduct**

https://www.apa.org/ethics/code/ethics-code-2017.pdf

If anyone is interested in the difficulties inherent in the field of cognitive-emotive patterns; applied ethics; and human justice just read this paper in combination with the DSM-5! The self-appointed experts in cognitive-emotive disabilities (DSM) paradoxically want to adhere to the highest degree of faith and loyalty yet do not want to be involuntarily judged by the legal system according to their own code of ethics! The code of ethics, however, incorporates and mimics both the ethics of the medical profession and the legal concepts of ethics applied to expert professions! The medical profession seeks to benefit patients and do no harm! The legal system sometimes forces people with superior knowledge and skill to benefit others with the highest degree of faith and loyalty!